# predict.svm does not predict new data

Tags: r, svm, libsvm, predict

unfortunately I have problems using predict() in the following simple example:

```
library(e1071)

x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)
test <- c(11:15)

mod <- svm(y ~ x, kernel = "linear", gamma = 1, cost = 2, type="C-classification")

predict(mod, newdata = test)
```

The result is as follows:

```
> predict(mod, newdata = test)
   1    2    3    4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
   0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1
```

Can anybody explain why predict() only gives the fitted values of the training sample (x,y) and does not care about the test-data?

Thank you very much for your help!

Richard

Comment: ps: using test <- c(11:25) gives "Error in names(ret2) <- rowns : 
  'names' attribute [15] must be the same length as the vector [10]"

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this is because you misuse the formula interface to `svm()`. Normally, one supplies a data frame or similar object within which the variables in the formula are searched for. It usually doesn't matter if you don't do this, even if it is not best practice, but when you want to predict, *not* putting variables in a data frame gets you in a right mess. The reason it returns the training data is because you don't provide `newdata` an object with a component named `x` in it. Hence it can't find the new data `x` so returns the fitted values. This is common for most R `predict` methods I know.

The solution then is to  i) put your training data in a data frame and pass `svm` this as the `data` argument, and ii) supply a new data frame containing `x` (from `test`) to `predict()`. E.g.:

```
> DF <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
> mod <- svm(y ~ x, data = DF, kernel = "linear", gamma = 1, cost = 2,
+ type="C-classification")
> predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = test))
1 2 3 4 5 
1 1 1 1 1 
Levels: 0 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You need newdata to be of the same form, ie using a data.frame helps:

```
R> library(e1071)
Loading required package: class
R> df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=sample(c(0,1), 10, rep=TRUE))
R> mod <- svm(y ~ x, kernel = "linear", gamma = 1, 
+             cost = 2, type="C-classification", data=df)
R> newdf <- data.frame(x=11:15)
R> predict(mod, newdata=newdf)
1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
R>
```

By the way, this is also shown the help page for `svm()`:

```
 ## density-estimation

 # create 2-dim. normal with rho=0:
 X <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000), b = rnorm(1000))
 attach(X)

 # traditional way:
 m <- svm(X, gamma = 0.1)

 # formula interface:
 m <- svm(~., data = X, gamma = 0.1)
 # or:
 m <- svm(~ a + b, gamma = 0.1)

 # test:
 newdata <- data.frame(a = c(0, 4), b = c(0, 4))
 predict (m, newdata)
```

So in sum, use the formula interface and supply a data.frame --- that is how essentially *all* modeling functions in R work.

Comment: Why are you defining a gamma parameter for a linear svm? Is that standard practice for linear svms in `e1071`? I have only ever seen those with RBF SVMs.

Comment: I will go and find my time machine to ask my younger self why I wrote that _nine years ago_ but form the context I _just cited the help page_ which may or may not have changed in the interim.

Comment: I didn't realize it was nine years ago sorry. I see the user used gamma as well. I was just curious because my question was why are we defining gamma for a linear svm in general.